# c# switch / case extra variable syntax

Tags: c#

In this code:

```
protected static void HandleExceptions(Exception E)
{
    switch (E)
    {
        case MongoWriteException _ :
        {
```

what does the discarded variable ('_' here) is supposed to be?

Comment: Exactly that. Discarded.

Comment: It's called pattern matching. See the marked duplicate, it should explain it. In summary `_` gets assigned the cast value of the switch if there is a type match.

Comment: Just saw, it's a cool feature; so, in the case of the code I posted it's useless then as it's discarded?

Comment: If you have no need to use the instance cast as `MongoWriteException` then you can remove `_`.